# Getting NVidia drivers and xrdp to play together on Docker on Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: ubuntu, remote-desktop, nvidia-graphics-card, xrdp

If I look around the internet, pages [like this one](https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/issues/1697#issuecomment-806578753) sort-of describe how to get NVidia drivers to work with `xrdp`, but the information is scattered and difficult to follow what exactly should be done.

So, it would be nice if there was a simple step-by-step solution to this problem - I want to get [`rviz`](http://wiki.ros.org/rviz) accelerated. Things I have tried:

##### Initial steps

- On Linux install [`virtualgl 2.6.5`](https://www.virtualgl.org/) in Docker
- On Windows, start up Remote Desktop and log onto `lightdm` on display `:10`.

##### Working but far from ideal

- On Linux in a standard terminal or from inside `VSCode`, load Docker and run `DISPLAY=:10 vglrun rviz`

This starts up `rviz` in the `xrdp` session, and checking `nvidia-smi` and `htop`, the GPU appears to be being used.

##### Not working properly

- On Windows in `PuTTY` or from inside `VSCode` or from a terminal inside `xrdp`, load Docker and run `DISPLAY=:10 vglrun -d :10 rviz`

This starts up `rviz` in the `xrdp` session, but checking `nvidia-smi` and `htop`, the GPU is **not** being used. The sample executable `glxspheres64` displays similar behaviour, so it's not just an `rviz` issue.

Has anyone here had success getting this to work?